# Python : Multiprocessing issues

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Python multiprocessing to run database backups on 60 independent linux machines in parallel. The estimated time for the longest running process is 6 hours. There are few that complete in 20 minutes.

```
import multiprocessing as mt
import subprocess

def remoteSSH(env, application, node, cmd):
    command1="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ForwardX11=no -l {} -n {} {}".format(application, node, cmd)
    command1=command1.split()
    process=subprocess.Popen(command1, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, stderr = process.communicate()
    returncode = process.returncode
    return [returncode, output, stderr]

def run_remote_db_backup(backup_database_meta):
    ds,env,application,node = backup_database_meta.split(':')
    cmd="/tmp/Backup.ksh >> /tmp/{}".format(ds)
    #cmd='uname -a'
    returncode, output, stderr = remoteSSH(env,application,node,cmd)
    print returncode, output, stderr
    print "{}:{}:{}".format(ds,node,cmd)

def backup_work(Master_Meta_Dictionary, logger_file, logger_stream):
    # backup_database_meta is a list 
    backup_database_meta = dataserver_to_work_on(Master_Meta_Dictionary)
    k=mt.Pool(len(backup_database_meta))
    result=k.map(run_remote_db_backup, backup_database_meta)
    k.close()
    k.join()

# Master_Meta_Dictionary is a list 
backup_work(Master_Meta_Dictionary, logger_file, logger_stream)
```

**Issues faced 1:** After the backup_work definition is done creating all the pids, the pids start running backup.ksh on the remote machines. The problem comes when the backup.ksh completes and I expect to see print below. But it only shows up once all the pids have completed their tasks. I am confused with this behavior, I expect to see prints as the definition completes. if I run a quick running command line "uname -a", it prints the print statement below.

```
print "{}:{}:{}".format(ds,node,cmd)
```

**Issues faced 2:** Sometimes all the pids complete their work , but just do not exit and remain hung.

Comment: using multithreading will be the same here (since you're creating subprocesses anyway), and avoids using multiprocessing/forking/the heavy stuff. avoid when you can.

Comment: Thanks Jean, Sadly this is one of the situations where we have to , no matter what. You mentioned subprocesses, do you think that creates and issue ?

Comment: ok, maybe you could save a subprocess call by dropping the ssh and using the `paramiko` library which is pure python implementation of ssh.